# Count and Row_Number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the top 5 `Zipcodes` for each `Store` with the highest Customers in them (zipcodes).

Please find below my query:

```
SELECT T.[Store], T.[ZipCode], Count(T.[Customer])

FROM ( SELECT  T.[Store], T.[ZipCode], 
      Count(T.[Customer])  row_number() over (Partition By T.[StoreGitanjali] Order By Count (T.[Customer]) desc) as RN 
       FROM [Marketing].[dbo].[Poscus] as T    
Group By T.[StoreGitanjali], T.[ZipCode]) as T    
where T.RN <=5    
Group By T.[StoreGitanjali], T.[ZipCode]
```

---

Please let me know how to use Count here in this scenario. 
Thank you!

Comment: please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text.

Comment: You don't need a COUNT in the outer query, and you need to name the count in the inner query. That should simply be:  `SELECT T.[Store], T.[ZipCode], T.CustomerCount FROM (SELECT  T.[Store], T.[ZipCode], 
      Count(T.[Customer]) AS CustomerCount, row_number() over ....`

Comment: To get this clear: You want 5 Zipcodes for each of the stores with the highest customers?  Or do you want the Zipcodes and customer counts of the Top 5 stores with the most customers?

Answer (score 2):

Example

```
CREATE TABLE #t 
    (
        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        Customer NVARCHAR(3),
        Store NVARCHAR(5),
        ZIP INT
    )
    INSERT INTO #t VALUES('a', 'XYZ', 1234)
                        ,('b', 'XYZ', 1234)
                        ,('c', 'PQR', 1231)
                        ,('d', 'PQR', 1231)
                        ,('e', 'PQR', 1231)
                        ,('f', 'XYZ', 1232)
                        ,('g', 'XYZ', 1232)
                        ,('h', 'XYZ', 1232)
                        ,('i', 'PQR', 1236)
                        ,('j', 'PQR', 1236)
                        ,('k', 'LMN', 1237)
    SELECT * FROM #t
```

[image]

**The solution is**, Set *WHERE part < 2* according to your requirement.

```
SELECT  TotalCustomer, Store, ZIP, Part FROM (
    SELECT  
        COUNT(1) AS TotalCustomer, 
        Store, 
        ZIP, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Store ORDER BY Store) AS Part 
    FROM #t
    GROUP BY Store, ZIP
) t
WHERE Part < 2
ORDER BY Part
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE
AS(
    SELECT Store
        ,Zip
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT Customer) AS CustCount
    FROM #t
    GROUP BY Store,Zip
    --ORDER BY Store,Zip
    )
SELECT A.*
FROM(
        SELECT *
            --,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Store ORDER BY CustCount DESC) AS DenRank
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Store ORDER BY CustCount DESC) AS DenRank
        FROM CTE
        --ORDER BY Store,Zip
    ) AS A
WHERE A.DenRank <= 2
```